# Is there any way to detect that the Microphone is disabled on a Windows Store App?

Tags: windows-store-apps

I want to detect if the user turned off the Microphone on a Windows Store app on the fly. I know that it is possible because Audio Recorder uses it. But how?

**UPDATE**: I want to be notified by an event that the microphone was disabled.

Is there anything to do with this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370810(v=vs.85).aspx

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can check it this way.

```
bool IsMicAvailable = true;
try
{
    var MyMediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
    var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
    settings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio;
    await MyMediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    IsMicAvailable = false;
}

if(IsMicAvailable)
    //TODO : The logic of recording audio
else
    //TODO : Display error message
```

Basically if microphone permission is off then `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` will occur and if microphone is not attached then `System.Exception` will occur & it contains message `Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00DABE0`

Comment: That's not what I want. I want to be notified by an event that the microphone has been disabled.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the microphone is currently recording?

Answer (score 2):

```
var deviceAccessInfo = DeviceAccessInformation.CreateFromDeviceClass(DeviceClass.AudioCapture);
deviceAccessInfo.AccessChanged += OnDeviceAccessChanged;

void OnDeviceAccessChangedDeviceAccessInformation sender, DeviceAccessChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Status == DeviceAccessStatus.DeniedByUser)
    ; // handle
    else if (args.Status == DeviceAccessStatus.Allowed)
    ; // handle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to do initalizeAsync and watch for error. Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh768223.aspx for more information.

On your latter question. No, there's no way to learn that permission status has changed.